# Customizing CollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to customize a collection view.

I built [this](https://github.com/moopoints/THX-Collection-View-Demo) little demo here and using tutorials I found online I was able to customize the collection view so that the neighboring cells would show on the left and right while still remaining a paging effect (to lock into each cell when scrolling). I did that by creating a sub class for CollectionViewFlowLayout.

Now I'd like to be able to scale down the neighboring cells (e.g. to 0.9) and scale them to 1.0 when they move into the center. Where and how would I implement this? In the sub class of CollectionViewFlowLayout or in the VC? Any hints are welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Collection view is a scroll view, so you can use "scrollViewDidScroll" delegate methods - get visible cells and set scaling transform based on how far each cell from the center.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells) {
        CGRect cellFrame = [self.collectionView convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view];
        // calculate the offset from center
        // apply scale transform
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes! I totally forgot about that! Will try and report back! Thanks @almas

Comment: I just tried adding your snippet to my sub class of CollectionViewFlowLayout and am getting this error back: "Property 'view' not found on object of type 'ThanksCollectionViewFlowLayout *'" - do I have to declare view within my sub class? Thanks!

Comment: You add this code to your view controller. And don't forget to set your view controller as a delegate of collection view.

Comment: Gotcha. My view controller class is in swift and I wouldn't know how to translate your snippet. Any hints?

Comment: Those are standard iOS api methods, you shouldn't have any problems writing this in swift =) Just search documentation for those methods.